# Creating Hyperlinks for Append(Response) Output

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can someone please help me out on how to create a hyperlink for the output from append(response).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Sid").change(function () {
        if (document.getElementById("Sid").selectedIndex == 0) {
            $("#Did").empty();
        }
        else {
            var SitId = $(this).val();
            debugger
          $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "/Dropdown/GetDeviceList?Sid=" + SitId,
                contentType: "html",
               success: function (response) {
                   debugger
                   $("#Did").empty();
                   $("#Did").append(response);
```

Comment: You should include an example of how the response will look like.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is a url string :

```
$("#Did").append(`<a href="${response}">link text</a>`)
```